# Is this question about identifying a (5e) spell mechanic from the "Fantasy High" YouTube series appropriate for the main site?

Tags: support, specific-question, on-topic

I've been watching *Fantasy High*, the series of 5e sessions filmed and posted on YouTube by alums of the website collegehumor.com. At a certain point, the DM has an NPC do something that uses a spell mechanic I can't identify. Would it be appropriate to post a question on main asking for help identifying it, along with a link to the video and an exact time stamp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That seems like a perfectly reasonable [content-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-identification) question. Linking to the source material is great, the only addition we'd want to see is that you also include a description in text in case the video goes away (we want the question to still be understandable in such a case) and for the benefit of those who can't watch the video.

Comment: I might also suggest keeping in mind that the spell mechanic used in the video may not be an official one (which would also be a valid answer to the question, if that's the case).